# Install multiple version of Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have following versions of oracle:

```
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.1.0  Production
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
```

And using Oracle Apex 5.1.

I want to install newest version of Apex but also want to keep current 5.1 version and all the projects in it.

My question is it possible to install multiple versions of Apex?

Answer (score 1):

You can only have one version of APEX running in an instance of an Oracle Database.

You can also have one version of APEX installed per pluggable database.